# How to work with try and except in python?

Tags: python, try-catch, except

This program has to analyze student numbers and if they are correct write them to one `list` and if not write them to another `list`. They are correct if they have eight digits and contain only numbers.

I however have no idea what to type when it comes to the `try` and `except` part.

If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
Valid_file = "ValidNumbers.txt"
Invalid_file = "InvalidNumbers.txt"
Data_file = "Data.txt"

def analyse_students(Data_file):
    lenth = len(Data_file)
    total = 0
    try:
    
    except: 
    
    return 0
    
def read(Data_file):
    count = 0
    student_list = []
    try:
        open(Data_file)
    except:
        print("Couldn't append file", Valid_file)
    return count, student_list

def write(student, status):
    if status:
        try:
            open(Data_file)
        except:
            print("Couldn't append file", Invalid_file)
    
count, student_list = read(Data_file)

print("Number of lines read", count)

for student in student_list:

    print("See output files")
```

Comment: Please upload a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What do you mean `i however have no idea what to type when it comes to the try except part`

Comment: What error did you get? syntax error try-except or not getting the desired result?

Comment: I didn't get an error It just does nothing.  I just have no idea what to type to make the program work.  The data_file contains a lsit of numbers that I need to sort but I don't know how to test the so that the numbers can be sent to their respective lists.

Comment: You need to use a context manager in order to write or open a file.

Comment: What is `total=0` here? Do you want to append the correct numbers into a list and return that list?

Answer (score 1):

Okey, so there a few things that need to be explained where.

### What is try-except used for?

It is used for catching errors raised by the program. Any code susceptible of raising an exception is inserted inside a `try` statement, and below that statement, any number of `except` statements with any single error that you want to catch.

```py
try:
    user_input = int(input('Give me a number: '))
except ValueError:
    print('That is not a number!')
```

### When should i use try-except?

It is not a good practice to use a `try-except` on every single line of code that could raise an error, because that may be half of it, or more. So when shall you use it? Simple, ask this question: **Do I want to do any custom action with that error being raised?** If the answer is *yes*, you are good to go.

### Catching `Exception` or empty `except`

As I see in your example, you are using an empty `except`. Using an empty `except` statement will catch every single error raised that the surrounded code, which is similar (but not the same) as catching `Exception`. The `Exception` class is the superclass of every single built-in exception in the Python environment that are non-system-exiting ([read here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions)) and its generally a bad practice to catch either all exceptions with `except:` or `Exception` with `except Exception:`. **Why?** Because you are not letting the user (or even you, the programmer) know what error you are handling. For example:

```
fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana']
try: 
    selection = fruits[int(input('Select a fruit number (0-2): '))]  
except Exception:
    print('Error!')
    # But wait, are you catching ValueError because the user did not input a number, 
    # or are you catching IndexError because he selected an out of bound array index? 
    # You don't know
```

### Catching multiple exceptions

Based on the previous example, you can use multiple `try-except` statements to difference which errors are being raised.

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana']
try: 
    selection = fruits[int(input('Select a fruit number (0-2): '))]  
except ValueError:
    print('That is not a number')
except IndexError:
    print('That fruit number does not exist!')
```

### Grouping exceptions

If there are two particular exceptions that you want to use for a same purpose, you can group them in a `tuple`:

```py
fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana']
try: 
    selection = fruits[int(input('Select a fruit number (0-2): '))]  
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    print('Invalid selection!')
```

### Your case

Based on this information, add those `try-except` blocks to your code, and see what possible errors that could be raised during its execution, asking the previously recommended question **Do I want to execute some custom action with this error?**

### Additionally

- There are `try-except-else` statements. See [here](https://geek-university.com/python/the-try-except-else-statements/)
- There are `try-except-finally` statements. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-341.html)
- You can combine them all in a `try-except1-except2...exceptN-else-finally` statement.
- I recommend you get familiar with built-in errors why practicing this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I understand it:

You want to append the correct student's numbers to a `list` and if they are wrong, append them in another `list`. The way to check if the students' numbers are correct is if they are numerals containing 8 digits.

Assuming `student` in your code refers to the numbers of the students: (use the `for loop` to iterate through the list of students. I have tried to solve your primary problem: `try and except`)

```
def analyse_students(Data_file):
    lenth = len(Data_file)
    total = 0
    try:
        if len(str(student)) == 8 and student in "1234567890":
            #append to a list(correct ones)
        elif not(lenth == 8 and Data_file in "1234567890"):
            #append to another list(wrong ones)  
        else:
            raise ValueError

    except Exception:
        #print something

    return 0
```

The `try` catches all the errors and `except` catches them. Thus we can ourselves `raise` an error (say `ValueError` here) and the `try` will catch that too and send it to `except` block where the error message will be printed.

The `raise` keyword raises an exception.

You can define what kind of error to `raise`, and the text to print to the user.

Hope this was helpful!